# Resonance of open tube, discrepency, nodes and antinodes reversed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, wavelength

Looking at a crazy Multitube shotgun microphone and trying to understand the authors

open end tube calculations. (I wonder if it is actually open ended.)

> https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Poptronics/60s/64/Pop-1964-06.pdf

The author says,

> "To calculate tube length, first find wavelength by dividing the speed of sound the frequency.  (1100 feet per second for practical purposes.) For example,the wavelength of 256 cycles equals 1100 ÷ 256, or 4.296 feet. Tubelength, however, is half this, or 2.14 feet, since tubes open at both ends resonate at a Wavelength twice as long as their length."

Now my experiment;

I have 22" (.559m) tube. 1100/300Hz = 3.66 ft, but it's open ended so divide by 2 = 1.833ft =22 inch = 0.559 meters.

With a mic setting at the open end I get resonance at 300hz. (Small, like I'm just off the node)?

(this is close to what the author says, but far from what the hyperphysics calculator finds.)

If I remove the tube the signal drops.

However, If I put the mic inside the pipe at the 1/2 length position I get 10 times the signal.

If I hold the mic in place and remove the tube, the signal drops to 1/40 of what it was with the tube.

I'm using the calculator at,

> http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/opecol.html

My measurements say I have a node at the open end and an antinode at the center of the tube. But.

the hyperphysics calculator says /*opposite*/ about open ended tubes.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
         Thank, Mikek
```

BTW, I have both an aluminum tube and PVC of the same ID, the PVC has about 1/3 more signal at mid tube.

Not what I expected.

Bonus points!

Is the tube open at both ends, he closes it of with a funnel and Microphone.  (see the article)

Does a closed of tube need a perfect seal?

If it is a perfect seal, do the 36 other tubes act as an open, making it open at both ends?

It does have an opening 36* times the size of the tube all pointing away from the mic end of the tube.

- the other 36 tubes in the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Microphones measure fluctuations in air *pressure*.  At the open end of the tubes the pressure is constrained to be atmospheric pressure.  In the middle of the tube there is a pressure antinode.
Diagrams for standing sound waves in tubes are often drawn showing *displacement* nodes and and antinodes perhaps because this matches with standing waves we can see in a string but that is not what we hear.
I first learned this when I had a chance to crawl through a giant tube with a standing wave in it at a science centre.  I assumed someone had marked the standing wave pattern incorrectly with nodes at the end until I heard it with my own ears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found a Khan academy page that explained this to me.  It all became clear. And now I'm off to try a closed end 1/4 wavelength tube with a mic at the closed end. I expect to get the same amplitude as a 1/2 wavelength tube mic'ed in the center. This would take a lot of mic's to built this shotgun mic, and I haven't figured out what it takes to add electret mics together. (maybe you can help?) Just poking at ideas, not sure which way to go yet.